# Clarifying four modes of handling /etc/resolv.conf in systemd-resolved

Tags: systemd, systemd-resolved

I have read about systemd-resolved.service https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-resolved.service.html and learnt four modes of handling /etc/resolv.conf.

1. /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf
2. /usr/lib/systemd/resolv.conf
3. /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
4. /etc/resolv.conf may be managed by other package

I have read it for several times, but still feel confused about how to determine which mode of /etc/resolv.conf I should choose as a normal user.

For example, I try to add some custom dns servers, so,

> 1. Add DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf and check /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf, 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 exist in it.
> 2. If symlinking /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf to /etc/resolv.conf, 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are gone in
>      /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf.

Update 1:

```
test@instance-1:~$ cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf 
...
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4

test@instance-1:/etc$ sudo ln -sf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf 
test@instance-1:/etc$ ls -alh /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Mar 18 07:22 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
test@instance-1:/etc$ sudo reboot

test@instance-1:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
domain c.prime-poetry-197705.internal
search c.prime-poetry-197705.internal. google.internal.
nameserver 169.254.169.254

test@instance-1:~$ cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf 
domain c.prime-poetry-197705.internal
search c.prime-poetry-197705.internal. google.internal.
nameserver 169.254.169.254

test@instance-1:~$ ls -alh /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Mar 18 07:22 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

Update 2:
symlinking from /etc/resolv.conf

```
test@instance-1:~$ sudo ln -sf /etc/resolv.conf /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf 
test@instance-1:~$ ls -alh /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 16 Mar 18 07:51 /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf -> /etc/resolv.conf
test@instance-1:~$ sudo reboot

test@instance-1:~$ ls -alh /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf 
-rw-r--r-- 1 systemd-resolve systemd-resolve 603 Mar 18 07:52 /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

Comment: What does `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` contain after you apply the symlink? Without seeing the contents of your file (before and after), it's hard to say what's happening. Could you have possibly reversed the order of the files when symlinking?

Comment: Like @ErikF said, make sure /run/systemd/resolve/resolve.conf ` is symlinked *from* `/etc/resolv.conf`, not *to*. I.e. `/etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/resolve.conf`.

Comment: @JohanMyréen, I mistook the direction of symlinking, but everything under /run remain in memory and the symlink is gone after reboot, isn't it?  And I still cannot find where my custom dns servers are.

Comment: The direction in Update 1 is correct. `/etc/resolv.conf` should be a symlink pointing to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolve.conf`.

Comment: @JohanMyréen I tried it on another computer and /etc/resolv.conf  was not be updated by other unknown reason. It worked as expected. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you are getting your IP configuration from DHCP, which overrides the DNS information in your `resolved.conf` file (from `systemd.network(5)`):

> ## `[DHCP]` SECTION OPTIONS
>
> [...]
>
> `UseDNS=` When `true` (the default), the DNS servers received from the
>   DHCP server will be used and take precedence over any statically
>   configured ones.
>
> This corresponds to the `nameserver` option in `resolv.conf(5)`.

Try adding the following to your `{networkname}.network` file (in `/etc/systemd/network`):

```
[DHCP]
UseDNS=false
```

Comment: I checked my system, and systemd-networkd is not enabled. So there is nothing under /etc/systemd/network. I tried to enable and start it and add configuration like you said, but /etc/resolv.conf is still changed to the content in my post by someone unknown.